# div align=center

Tags: html, css, dhtml

How i can do a alignement of table div inside div to  align=center

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:100px;">asd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
div.a{
    margin-left:auto
    margin-right:auto
}
```