# Container won't centre....Can't work it out

Tags: html, css

This should be a very simple procedure of putting a container in the centre of the page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
    #container{
       width:960px;
       float:left;
       margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
...
<div id="container">
   Content
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why `container` isn't centered?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean horizontally centered, vertically or both?

Comment: I happened to notice that your CSS is not in `<style>` tags. In the interest of not making assumptions, might that be the reason your styles aren't working?

Comment: try this; `text-align: center;` in #container

Comment: This question has been asked probably 1000x: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445133/html-center-align-not-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412971/working-with-css-to-align-center http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202612/div-align-center

Comment: If he sets `text-align: center;` on `#container` he'll center the text in the container. :p

Comment: It's because I included float:left...the answers below helped me realise this. @Codemonkey the code was in the styles tags, I just removed it for ease on here. Thanks for your replies. Christoph I know it's been answered before and I looked but couldn't work it out! Was the float element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523632/aligning-a-floatleft-div-to-center "you can't centre floats"

Comment: But it's okay, if it helped you. Just accept an answer and look for answers more thoroughly next time;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`margin:0 auto;` gives auto margin to left and right and that would make it center.

if its not centered that would be because of the `float:left;`

Comment: Why are you repeating back the title and question in your answer? Please just answer the question and leave the unnecessary stuff out.

Comment: Because they contradict each other... witch is weird, so i wanted to know what he ment?

Comment: It was a typo when I put 'is'...I mean't 'isn't' and removing the float:left fixed this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I know, but it's fairly obvious what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You're welcome, And flag the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Makura, they always foret to do so :) here is an upvote from me at least ;)

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean "**isn't** appearing"?

Set `text-align:center;` on `body` and remove `float:left;` from `#container`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant bud. All fixed. Removed the float! Ta.

Comment: Don't forget the center alignment on the body. Some browsers need that.

Comment: Interesting, which browsers need this?